# Cron @reboot running pm2 not starting node script

Tags: node.js, cron

I am trying to use pm2 (also tried forever) to start a node script @reboot in cron but nothing seems to work. I am using Amazon Linux 2 on an EC2 instance.

**Crontab:**

```
@reboot sleep 60; cd /var/api/ && /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.1/bin/pm2 start /var/api/server-api.js >> /var/log/api.log
```

**whereis node**

```
node: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.1/bin/node
```

**whereis pm2**

```
pm2: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.1/bin/pm2
```

/var/log/cron has the following entry showing it at least tried to execute:

```
(root) CMD (sleep 60; cd /var/api/ && /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.1/bin/pm2 start /var/api/server-api.js >> /var/log/api.log)
```

and /var/log/api.log is completely blank.

Comment: Why not a systemd unit file?

Comment: @Marc Because Im not familiar with that.

Comment: https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1#creatingasystemdservicefile & https://serverfault.com/a/1030572/569434 & https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/running-node-js-linux-systemd

Comment: @Marc Thanks! The 3rd article really helped.